# Speed difference in np.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I noticed that `np.einsum` is faster when it reduces one dimension

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((100,100,100))
b = np.random.random((100,100,100))

%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ijk',a,b)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',a,b)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 937 µs per loop
%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->i',a,b)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 921 µs per loop
%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->',a,b)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 928 µs per loop
```

Which seems very weird to me, as I would expect it to first generate the new array and then sum over it, which is obviously not happening.
What is going on there? Why is it getting faster, when one drops one dimnesion, but does not get faster after other dimension drops?

Side note:
I first thought that it has to do with creating a large array, when it has many dimensions, which I don't think is the case:

```
 %timeit np.ones(a.shape)
 # 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop
 %timeit np.empty(a.shape)
 # 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 µs per loop
```

As creating new arrays is way faster.

Answer (score 1):

`einsum` is implemented in compiled code, `numpy/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src`.

The core operation is to iterate over all dimensions (e.g. in your case `100*100*100` times) using the `c` version of `nditer`, applying the `sum-of-products` calculation defined by the `ijk` string.

But it does various optimizations, including generating views if no multiplication is required.  So it will require careful study to see what's different in your cases.

The time divide is between producing a 3d output without summations, and one that sums on one or more axis.